# Ansible Installation - Redhat 6.10 Python3.6.6, Python 2.6

Tags: python, installation, ansible

I am on a machine with Python 2.6 installed by default, and Python 3.6.6 added to it.

I am trying to install the stand-alone ansible on an offline machine using the RPM file.  My machine is RHEL 6.10.  It is an offline machine if that matters. I do not have access to the vast majority of repository files but can bring individual files in if needed.

Upon doing

```
rpm -i ansible-2.9.2-1.el7.noarch.rpm
```

I receive an issue with errors of Python packages for Python2.7 I do not have installed yet, as well as the fact that I do not have Python 2.7.  However, I do have Python 3.6.6, which meets the minimum requirements of ansible.  How can I get it to see this and ignore the fact that I do not have Python 2.7?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this command and see minimal requirements of Ansible 2.9//

```
rpm -qpR ansible-2.9.2-1.el7.noarch.rpm
```

if python 2.7 is minimal requirement to install that rpm package, you can try alternative method i.e., by installing ansible using pip (pip3) package in python3 environment.

```
pip3 install ansible
```

Comment: also note that, you mentioned that your machine is RHEL 6.X and this rpm package is of el7.. Enterprise Linux 7

Answer (score 0):

Try `python3.6 -m pip install ansible` . Worked for me.